# Objective-C clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, apache, cordova, clang

I have a problem when I try to compile my project. The following is the error message. Please help me fix this.

> Ld /Users/dmitriy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SureFireMessenger-hhpmyrmmtyjmjvajfqgednatyetg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SureFireMessenger.app/SureFireMessenger normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/dmitriy/Documents/Developments/Fire Messenger/platforms/ios"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/dmitriy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SureFireMessenger-hhpmyrmmtyjmjvajfqgednatyetg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dmitriy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SureFireMessenger-hhpmyrmmtyjmjvajfqgednatyetg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/dmitriy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SureFireMessenger-hhpmyrmmtyjmjvajfqgednatyetg/Build/Intermediates/SureFireMessenger.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SureFireMessenger.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SureFireMessenger.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -force_load /Users/dmitriy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SureFireMessenger-hhpmyrmmtyjmjvajfqgednatyetg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework ImageIO -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AddressBook -weak_framework AddressBookUI -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dmitriy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SureFireMessenger-hhpmyrmmtyjmjvajfqgednatyetg/Build/Intermediates/SureFireMessenger.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SureFireMessenger.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SureFireMessenger_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dmitriy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SureFireMessenger-hhpmyrmmtyjmjvajfqgednatyetg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SureFireMessenger.app/SureFireMessenger
>
> ld: file not found: /Users/dmitriy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SureFireMessenger-hhpmyrmmtyjmjvajfqgednatyetg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Did you add Cordova library to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the "libCordova.a" file, a static library file is missing.

Are you sure you wired up everything correctly?